# Homotopy types of causal / chronological pathspaces in Lorentzian manifolds?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Lorentzian manifold, and let $p,q \in M$. Let $\Pi^J(p,q)$ be the space of causal paths from $p$ to $q$ (in the compact-open topology).

**Question 1:** Is it reasonable to expect that the homotopy type of $\Pi^J(p,q)$ is "not too bad"?

For instance, we might assume that $M$ is globally hyperbolic with some kind of energy condition, and ask whether $\Pi^J(p,q)$ is of finite type (i.e. has finitely-generated homotopy groups in all degrees). Or we might ask whether $\pi_1(\Pi^J(p,q))$ is abelian at all basepoints.

As a sanity check, in Minkowski space $\Pi^J(p,q)$ is always empty or contractible.

**Question 2:** Same question, but about the space $\Pi^I(p,q)$ of timelike paths from $p$ to $q$.

**Question 3:** Is the inclusion $\Pi^I(p,q) \to \Pi^J(p,q)$ a weak homotopy equivalence (probably not!)? At any rate, is it a reasonably well-behaved map homotopy-theoretically?

Comment: In the globally hyperbolic case, if anything it should depend on the topology of the Cauchy hypersurface, and the latter can pretty much be arbitrary. Are you implicitly using the energy conditions to control the topology of the Cauchy hypersurface? That's the only way I can imagine energy conditions being relevant to your question.

Comment: @WillieWong I'm definitely out of my depth here -- I don't actually know anything about energy conditions! But in the globally hyperbolic case, the causal diamond $J(p,q)$ from $p$ to $q$ is compact and finite-dimensional. If we knew, for example, that $J(p,q)$ were a (retract of a) finite CW complex, then we would know that the full pathspace $\Pi_{J(p,q)}(p,q)$ from $p$ to $q$ through $J(p,q)$ is "not too bad", being homotopy equivalent to the based loopspace $\Omega J(p,q)$. Now, $\Pi^J(p,q)$ is a subspace of $\Pi_{J(p,q)}(p,q)$, but this doesn't guarantee that it's not more complex.

Comment: For $\Pi^I(p,q)$, at least, which is defined by an open ordinary differential relation, there should be something that can be said from an h-principle perspective, I think.

Comment: I know next to nothing about topology, but you do. So: given an arbitrary Riemannian manifold with points $p, q$ with a distance < 1, how bad can the space of all curves from p to q with length $\leq 1$ get? What you are looking for is at least as bad as that.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: Morales Álvarez, Pablo(E-GRANS-GT); Sánchez, Miguel(E-GRANS-GT)
A note on the causal homotopy classes of a globally hyperbolic spacetime. (English summary)
Classical Quantum Gravity 32 (2015), no. 19, 197001, 12 pp. https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02376